# Feasibility living tissue product

Tags: science-based, science-fiction

Once upon a time, there was a gang that wanted young women to infiltrate the upper class. Unfortunately due to genetic modification and better nutrition the elite was much taller two feet on average so to fake a bigger upper body I was thinking of using padding with artificial skin over it akin to https://terminator.fandom.com/wiki/Living_tissue
Is this possible with current technology and science? The criteria is someone touching the spy and not noticing anything unusual.

Comment: How are you going to fake the head and arms? Those need to do things, and the real head and arms need to be concealed, without blocking the eyes.

Comment: If all you want is extra height what is wrong with simply breaking their legs and adding bone grafts so they're taller? something that makes far more sense and we both can and do do with current tech, the same can be done as easily for the arms if you want to insure they're proportional to the legs.

Comment: How is padding the upper body going to increase height? You're upper body can be as bulky as you like but no matter how fat or muscly you are it won't add a centimetre of height so wtf are you talking about? a fake body suite with your head in its chest and a fake head on top of your head? how do expect that to work? how do you expect that to fool anyone within conversational range? is the head animatronic or something? is such a thing (sufficient to fool anyone close to them) possible with our current technology? No it is most definitely not possible to that standard with current technology.

Comment: Leg arm transplants as per a BBC news article I found.

Comment: Have no solution for the head. But something along the lines of padded helmet

Comment: And of course like in the episode of Seinfeld special shoes

Comment: It is sort of a trippy SF concept.  If I saw it in the movie I would wonder what the metaphor was supposed to be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## No:

Current science does not yet have the level of control over tissue growth to make a second functioning life form that covers the original person and provide even remotely functional abilities. We barely can graft tissue from the same person on to different parts of the body or replace similar organs.

Having living tissue over an existing person will only make the task more complex. Then you have a second entire functional organism that needs separate organs, respiration, and circulation.

## But Wait, There's Hope...

Okay, you probably can't make a person's torso bigger without some pretty extreme surgery. For that, weight gain will make things wider, but not taller. Even the "rings around the neck" process that seems to lengthen the neck mostly just crushes down the shoulders. No prosthetic, living or otherwise, will do much for that. You may be able to create the illusion of a longer torso with clothes, style and bearing. A suit won't help.

There are options for the limbs, however.

In a less-than perfect and slow process, limbs can be broken, pried apart and inserts put in to lengthen bones. This would be a VERY slow process for the kinds of lengths you're talking about, leave the person kind-of crippled  up, and be excruciating. I'm not entirely convinced it would work for a two foot change.

You stand a chance with limb replacement, where you remove existing limbs and swap them with someone who has longer ones. There is likely to be damage, loss of function, and serious rejection issues. We just don't know enough about repairing and re-interfacing nerves OR controlling rejection. It MIGHT pass, but isn't great. If it was, all our amputees would just get replacement limbs.

We are getting closer to the point where we can successfully replace one limb or organ with another, such that it is functional and fully integrated without rejection. In the near term, this would likely involve denuding an existing limb of cells and growing new tissue on the extracellular matrix of the old limb. But you would need a "longer" limb to replace the smaller ones, and we would need to learn a fair amount about nerve growth and control. Since you are rebuilding the tissue, you might be able to insert sections of bone in a somewhat shorter limb and then regenerate the cell matrix. It would take care of the rejection issue, though.

Soon, we will likely be able to 3D print extracellular matrix with the appropriate developmental signals on it to cause stem cells to fill in and differentiate into the appropriate tissue. There would still be some issues, but at that point the tissue would be grown from the person's own cells. You simply grow them new arms and legs in proportion to the size you want.

I can't guarantee you could have the torso-to-limb ratios look exactly right, but the result would be a lot closer.

Comment: You don't need to replace limbs to lengthen them, just break the long bones use clamps to force the bone apart at the break and insert sections of sterilised bone (sheep, pig, whatever, doesn't matter where it came from if you boil it long enough first), clamp and splint the limb, allow time for living bone and tissue to migrate into the fresh calcium inserts and new bone growth to mend the breaks and job done, do the same for the arms to ensure they're proportional if you want, it's not a million miles from some well established pretty routine procedures to lengthen limbs we've done for ages.

Comment: ^ it's normally done in stages over months or years to allow the soft tissues to stretch and grow as well, it or something like it is (or has been) used as a treatment for some developmental / growth problems .. [checks DWKraus bio] .. huh! .. but I didn't really need to tell you any of that did I  a simple reminder of the existence of leg lengthening surgery was probably, or should have been, more than enough 

Comment: @Pelinore Yes, you could do that, but we're talking two feet.  I also assumed (perhaps wrongly, but hey) that they didn't want to wait years before inserting agents, since otherwise they could simply raise new women with the mentioned "better nutrition" to get them to the right height.  I also assumed they wanted an answer related to growing new tissue (as close to the original request as possible).  But I'll add some mentioning of your points. Thx

Comment: Fair assumptions  // unrelated (or only tangentially so) additional query / comment: always wondered why they don't use the bone inserts I suggest in the actual procedure, should speed up the whole process considerably and allow the removal of the implanted medical clamps / vices (whatever they're actually called) much sooner I'd have thought?

Comment: @Pelinore Inserting bone into bone is trickier than it sounds. Not sure non-human bone would work, or just boiling the bone. They are doing some really interesting work into "filler" matrixes to repair bone (often made of crushed bone or hydroxyapatite) that may work as well.

Comment: Well pig cartilage stripped of any living cells is fine for transplant, we use that for heart valve replacement after all, so I presumed, suitably denuded of all living cells of course, that bone would also be suitable for appropriate procedures, would provide a suitable lattice for bone tissues and new bone growth, while also providing a little structural support from the get go, once you've stripped out all the cells it's just calcium after all, cut to size, carve to shape, slot in and pin in place with bone dowels was what I was thinking.

Comment: @Pelinore They use beef valves as well. In those cases, the functional part of the valves is the cartilage, that doesn't grow or repopulate (it's basically a biologically-derived mechanical part). The valves mechanically work, but wear out after about ten years. The bone actually needs to grow and repopulate with cells for the osteoblasts  to connect the materials. You can strip off cells with a mild detergent, but you need the extracellular matrix for the cells to know what to "do" at any given location.

Comment: Would the methods used to strip out living cells from valves also strip out the extracellular matrix then? Collagen is at least part of the extracellular matrix in bone I thought and seeing as that's mostly what the cartilage a pig valve is made of consists of I wouldn't have thought so?

Comment: @Pelinore The methods to prepare valves are crude compared to the denuding process I'm talking about. They've stripped a mouse heart of all cells and recolonized it with recipient cells, then successfully implanted it. They don't use it yet on humans, but it's technically possible (just not safe yet). As of today, you still need to implant living bone.

Comment: *"The methods to prepare valves are crude compared to the denuding process I'm talking about"* which surely makes it even more likely bone can be denuded of living cells while still retaining the extracellular matrix?

Comment: @Pelinore Yes, it will be possible in the near future. Not with current technology, unfortunately, but there's nothing Earth-shaking that can't be invented. It won't necessarily work with non-human bone, because the developmental signals would potentially be wrong for human cells. And since humans live so much longer, their stem cells are a lot harder to work with than mice (plus if you kill 80% of mice, it's a success. Kill 20% of humans and it's a horrifying failure). There are also increased risks of infection with these types of grafts. But yes, it's really exciting stuff!